# Can imenu be made to rescan every time?

Tags: imenu

Is it possible to make imenu refresh on *every* access, and to remove the `*Rescan*` item from the menu?

Comment: Variable `imenu-auto-rescan`:  "*Non-nil means Imenu should always rescan the buffers.*"  I do not know if that resolves the `*Rescan*` from appearing in the list and will not be testing that aspect/feature this evening, sorry.

Comment: Checked the code, seems there is no option *not* to add the rescan menu item.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the rescan item an empty string, maybe that's good enough.

```
(setq imenu-auto-rescan t
      imenu-auto-rescan-maxout (* 1024 1024)
      imenu--rescan-item '("" . -99))
```

Here's some advice on some internal imenu functions that actually removes the rescan item.  I think I got the corner cases, but it might break in the future.

```
(defun jpk/imenu-no-rescan-item (ret)
  (when (and imenu-auto-rescan (<= (buffer-size) imenu-auto-rescan-maxout))
    (setq ret (delq imenu--rescan-item ret)))
  ret)
(advice-add 'imenu--make-index-alist :filter-return #'jpk/imenu-no-rescan-item)
(advice-add 'imenu--split-menu :filter-return #'jpk/imenu-no-rescan-item)
```

You should make a bug report to get a proper fix in.  It seems silly to have the rescan item if auto rescan is enabled.

Comment: @ideasman42 you should get an email with the assigned bug number.

Comment: But report sent.